# TYPO3 tt_news: Add new attribute to link

Tags: typo3

I want to add a new attribute to *tt_news* link, such as an id, class or onclick function.
How can I do this?

Comment: Which link do you want to modify? The link to the single news item (`###TEMPLATE_SINGLE###`)? Note that the tt_news id is already attached.

Comment: yes, i would like to modify the single news item.for example when i click on the news i would like get a popup in which the news content to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, there is no typoscript solution to add more attributes to the "more"-link in tt_news `displayList` and `displayLatest` views. you would have to hack the extension - wich is not a good idea (*).

if you only need it to call a javascript function, then the easy solution is to use jQuery or another framework to add click-listeners to the `a` tags. an example in jQuery:

```
$('div.news-msg a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent link from opening

    var newsurl = $(this).attr('href');
    //...do more stuff...
});
```

(*) don't take my word for it - see the following discussions (in german):
 http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege/thema/27238/ or http://www.typo3.net/forum/beitraege/thema/67165/